# exec not working or executing crontab script

Tags: php, cron

Basically I have developed a small script that adds a cron job into a file called "crontask" and then I want to execute it so then it becomes a cron job. Here is the script:

```
 <?php

    $filename = "../../tmp/crontask.txt";
    $output = shell_exec('crontab -l');
    $something = file_put_contents($filename, $output.'* * * * * NEW_CRON'.PHP_EOL);
    $cngDir = chdir('../../tmp/');
    echo exec('crontab ' . getcwd() . '/crontask.txt');
    //var_dump($exe);
```

?>

Everything is ok, the path is the same and if I copy and paste the path that prints out IT will carry out the cronjob but in PHP it won't???

Everything works, apart from the exec function, it doesn't execute it. Any ideas?

In terminal, if I do:

```
string(25) "crontab /tmp/crontask.txt"
```

it will execute it.

Comment: I've never used php in my life, but isn't "crontab file" supposed to **replace** an existing crontab rather than append to it? Have a look at mailx(1) as well to make sure the invocation is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following things:

- Call to the command using the full command path. Sometimes $PATH is not set in the script environment and can't find the command if not.
- Setup the working dir of the script using http://php.net/manual/en/function.chdir.php
- Use the absolute path to access to the file

Comment: @Mals3w Still won't work. I have updated my code (In original post) can you take a look please?

Comment: Try with absolute paths. Remember use `__DIR__` (echo it for see where is your script)

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar issue with cron jobs
I looked at your code and got a couple of ideas.
I used absolute paths

Here is my code:

```
$myFile = "/home/user/tmp/crontab.txt";
$addcron = "
0     0     *     *     *      cronjob1 " . PHP_EOL .
"0    18     *     *     1-5    conjob2 " . PHP_EOL .
"0     9     *     *     *      cronjob3 " . PHP_EOL  ;

$output = exec('crontab -l  > ' . $myFile );
file_put_contents($myFile,$addcron ,FILE_APPEND);
echo exec('crontab ' . $myFile );
echo "<h3>Cron job successfully added!</h3>";enter code here
```

basically i wrote the list of previous cronjobs to a file and then appended the file with new cronjobs. Then added the new list of cronjobs with the crontab command.
the linux write to file command ' > ' was what did the trick ;)